# RewriteRule is applied to all files during directory listing

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, directory-listing

With `Options Indexes` and `LogLevel rewrite:trace6` I see that my rewrite rule is applied to all files in the directory being listed. It even goes inside sub-directories and looks for `index.html`. This is bad for performance. Is this really necessary? How to disable it? In the actual configuration I have a "prg" `RewriteMap` and this program receives all listed files on its STDIN.

The problem is reproducible with this minimum of configuration:

**Environment:**

- OpenSUSE Tumbleweed
- apache2-2.4.51-1.1.x86_64

**Configs:**

- `/etc/apache2/conf.d/test.conf` (see below the full httpd.conf)

  ```
  LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
  LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
  <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/test">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule badrule neverhappen
  </Directory>
  ```

**Commands:**

```
mkdir /srv/www/htdocs/test
touch /srv/www/htdocs/test/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{a..z}
systemctl restart apache2
tail -F /var/log/apache2/error_log &
curl -s -o /dev/null http://localhost/test/
```

**Output:**

```
[rid#556dab9a2060/initial] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/test/ ->
[rid#556dab9a2060/initial] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] applying pattern 'badrule' to uri ''
[rid#556dab9a2060/initial] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/test/
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/test/index.html -> index.html
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] applying pattern 'badrule' to uri 'index.html'
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/test/index.html
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/test/index.html.var -> index.html.var
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] applying pattern 'badrule' to uri 'index.html.var'
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/test/index.html.var
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/test/HEADER.html -> HEADER.html
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] applying pattern 'badrule' to uri 'HEADER.html'
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/test/HEADER.html
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/test/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzza -> zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzza
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] applying pattern 'badrule' to uri 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzza'
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/test/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzza
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/test/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzb -> zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzb
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] applying pattern 'badrule' to uri 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzb'
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/test/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzb
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/htdocs/test/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzc -> zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzc
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] applying pattern 'badrule' to uri 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzc'
[rid#556dab9a8090/subreq] [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/test/] pass through /srv/www/htdocs/test/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzc
...
```

**Full `httpd.conf`:**

```
# sudo -u nobody /sbin/httpd -d /etc/httpd-test -f /etc/httpd-test/httpd.conf -DFOREGROUND
#
# The following is not needed on SUSE
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# The following is not needed on SUSE
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so

LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule autoindex_module  modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so

ErrorLog "|/bin/cat"
LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
PidFile /dev/shm/httpd-test.pid

ServerName localhost

Listen 8080

DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"

<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/test">
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule badrule neverhappen
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a directory listing generated by mod_autoindex an internal subrequest is triggered for all listed items in the directory. This is indicated in the log with `subreq` (as opposed to `initial`).

You can prevent the `RewriteRule` directive being processed for subrequests by using the `NS` (`nosubreq`) flag. For example:

```
RewriteRule badrule neverhappen [NS]
```

Alternatively, you can move the `RewriteRule` directive out of the `<Directory>` container and have it directly under the `<VirtualHost>` instead. Note that the directive *might* need to be changed
slightly since it's now working in a different [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) (*virtualhost* as opposed to *directory*) and processed earlier. This naturally prevents the directive being processed for each item in the directory listing (without having to include the `NS` flag). However, it can still be called for other subrequests, such as calls for [`HeaderName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername) and [`ReadmeName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#readmename) files associated with the directory listing (if these directives are set, regardless of whether the files exist or not), so you may still choose to include the `NS` flag on these directives if this is an issue.

> It even goes inside sub-directories and looks for `index.html`

This is caused by mod_dir testing for `DirectoryIndex` documents. If this is not required then it can be disabled:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Reference:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ns
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex